# How to read the power of a polynomial term?

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials

Consider the following polynomial

```
15*x-22*x**3+14*x**40
```

I know how to extract the coefficients of this polynomial easily enough but I cannot find a command that will read the power of the terms. Is there a way other than dividing and cancelling to find them? In this case the output would be along the lines of

```
np.array([1,3,40])
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse a string representing the polynomial?

Comment: Are you looking for a [Poly.terms](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.terms)?

Comment: Hi Soon, Poly.terms is exactly what i need. Thank you very much. If you could post that as an answer, I'll mark it correct. Cheers for that

Comment: @soon tagging you so you don't miss the opportunity for answering this :) James, Stack Overflow will only notify the writers of a comment if you specifically tag them using @+name.

Comment: @roganjosh thank you. I didn't know that.

Comment: @roganjosh, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sympy.Poly` provides the [`terms`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.terms) method, which returns all non-zero polynomial terms:

```
In [19]: from sympy import poly

In [20]: p = poly('15*x-22*x**3+14*x**40')

In [21]: p.terms()
Out[21]: [((40,), 14), ((3,), -22), ((1,), 15)]
```